# Is it possible to first resolve promises, then set an array, then create a directive for each item?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to execute code in a few steps. Is it possible to do?

1. First I want to resolve all of these promises

   ```
   $scope.recentReported = [];

   $scope.getRecentReported = function () {
     var dateToday = new Date();
     for (i = 0; i < $scope.recentDateLength; i++) {
       var dateThen = moment(dateToday).add(-i, 'days');
       RestRequestsSrvc.getRevenue(dateThen)
         .then(
           function (response) {
             if (response) {
               $scope.recentReported.push(response.date);
             }
           }
         );
     }
   };
   ```
2. When the promises have resolved I want to calculate `$scope.recentUnreported` based on `$scope.recentReported`. It will be an array containing the dates that were not in `$scope.recentReported`.
3. Once that is done I want to ng-repeat a directive for every date in `$scope.recentUnreported`

Comment: you can chain promises and in the alst one set `$scope.recentReported` also in a directive watch `$scope.recentReported` if changed then do the logic. here is a grate article about promises http://solutionoptimist.com/2013/12/27/javascript-promise-chains-2/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular promise in async loop function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21903453/angular-promise-in-async-loop-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like the following? Code is untested.

JavaScript

```
$scope.recentReported = [];

$scope.getRecentReported = function () {
  var dateToday = new Date();
  var promises = [];
  for (i = 0; i < $scope.recentDateLength; i++) {
    var dateThen = moment(dateToday).add(-i, 'days');
    promises.push(RestRequestsSrvc.getRevenue(dateThen));
  }
  $q.all(promises).then(function(response){
      for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++){
          $scope.recentReported.push(response[i].date);
      }

      $scope.recentUnreported = $scope.getUnreported(); // Do what you need to do.
  });
};
```

HTML

```
<div my-directive ng-repeat="unreported in recentUnreported"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wait for all promises to be resolved using [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

You will then get a single promise which, once resolved, will have an array of values, that is what you're probably looking for.

Comment: If he's using promises in AngularJS, then maybe `$q.all()` is what he should use in this case.

Comment: Good point. However, as long $q is Promise A+ compliant, no harms should be done ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use $q.all(promises) [see here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) This gives you a promise that will be resolved as soon as all promises are resolved.

Hope that helps.