# angular $q.all when dynamically assigning event listeners in loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, q

I've found [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21903453/angular-promise-in-async-loop-function) that detail the same problem of an async operation in a loop but I'm still having trouble with the $q syntax.

Basically, I have this:

```
controller: ["fooService", function(fooService) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.events = [
        {
            iconClass: { on: "icon-is-active", off: "icon-is-not-active" },
            event: "click",
            fn: function(self) { self.isActive = !self.isActive; },
            isActive: fooService.foobar //initialized to true elsewhere
        },
        {
            iconClass: { on: "icon-is-active", off: "icon-is-not-active" },
            event: "mouseup",
            fn: function(self) { self.isActive = !self.isActive; },
            isActive: fooService.barfoo //initialized to false elsewhere
        }
    ];
}];
```

And need to do this...

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
    for (var i = 0; i < ctrl.events.length - 1; i++) {
        elem[0].on(ctrl.events[i], function() {
            scope.$apply(function() {
                ctrl.events[i].fn(ctrl.events[i]); 
            });
        });
    } 
}
```

...in order to get this view working:

```
<my-button ng-repeat="event in vm.events">
    <i ng-class="event.isActive ? event.iconClass.on : event.iconClass.off"></i>
</my-button>
```

The above doesn't work, so you can (crudely) wrap it in a closure...

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
    for (var i = 0; i < ctrl.events.length - 1; i++) {

        (function($event) {
            elem[0].on(ctrl.events[i], function() {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    ctrl.events[i].fn(ctrl.events[i]); 
                });
            });
        })(event);

    } 
}
```

But now we've lost reference to our original objects, and other parts of the application can't toggle the `iconClass` or `isActive` state of each object we've passed to the event listener despite being originally bound to a service. I've tried to learn $q several times but could use some help honestly.

```
var promises = [];

for (var i = 0; i < ctrl.events.length - 1; i++) {
    promises.push(function() {
        return elem[0].on(ctrl.events[i].event, function() {
            scope.$apply(function() {
                ctrl.events[i].fn(ctrl.events[i]);
            });
        });
    });
}

$q.all(promises);
```

(Nothing happens there)

Comment: last line doesn't have a callback which is needed to run whatever code you want run when the promises have resolved

Comment: Why `for (var i = 0; i < ctrl.events.length - 1; i++)`?? Shouldn't it be `for (var i = 0; i < ctrl.events.length; i++)`. Seems like you are skipping the last item.